# what does Cons do in this function?

Tags: sml, lazylist

I'm confused as to what the `Cons()` function does, in the function definition for from.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What `Stream` represents is a [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) and potentially infinite list. Since SML is [eager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation), this needs to be done in a slightly roundabout way.

Let's first look at how ordinary lists work:

```
datatype 'a list = [] | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

The cons consists of two parts:

- The first element in the list
- The rest of the list

In the lazy list, it's pretty similar.

```
datatype 'a Stream = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a Stream)
```

Here the cons consists of the following:

- The first element in the list
- *A function that produces* the rest of the list *when evaluated on `()`*

So, you can see that the principle is much the same, albeit a tad more difficult to work with.

Let's look at an example list:

```
fun succ n = Cons (n, fn () => succ (n+1))
val naturals = succ 0
```

What does this produce? Let's examine it.

`naturals` was defined to be `succ 0`, which in turn is defined to be `Cons(0, fn () => succ 1)`. From this we can see that the first element in the list is `0`.

Now let us go one step further. We evaluate `fn () => succ 1`, the second part of our `Cons`, on `()`, which produces `succ 1`, which in turn is `Cons(1, fn () => succ 2)`. Now we can see that the second element in the list is `1`.

If we repeat this process, we get that the list represents the infinite list `[0, 1, 2, ...]`.

You can also see this by trying to do

```
val firstnats = take 10 naturals;
```

and seeing what you get.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of Stream's two constructors.  See the second line of that screenshot -- that's all there is to Cons.